# Conditional package import for desktop in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I know that the availability of `dart.library.html` can be used as the condition for web, but what about desktop?

Although I suppose you can import a particular package for desktop and not for mobile if you create and use a new package in which different packages are specified for different platforms in `pubspec.yaml` as explained in [the document](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin-platforms),
it seems a little redundant to make such a package for that purpose.

Is it possible just by using a statement of the `import 'foo.dart' if (...) 'bar.dart'` style, and if possible, what library is put in its `if (...)` part?

Comment: I don't know about the import, but you can use the [Platform class properties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html#static-properties) to check which operating system your app is running, this gives you the possibility to make different widgets for each Platform.

Comment: It seems that Desktop version of flutter also uses dart.library.io, so ```import 'foo.dart' if (dart.library.io) 'bar.dart'``` should work for mobile and Desktop, give it a try.

Comment: What I'd like to do is to import a package suitable for each platform as I mentioned, "a particular package for desktop and not for mobile".

Comment: That's the best I could come up with, we'll need someone else's help here. Sorry I couldn't help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use conditional imports to get different behavior between mobile and desktop; see [this comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34262#issuecomment-416129832) from the Dart team.